# Uploading image using FormData and Ajax not working, Undefined Index error message

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using FormData and Ajax to pass a file to upload from the View to the Controller in Codeigniter. Passing the uploaded file has to be made using Ajax. Below is the code I'm using. If I don't include the line `form.append("photoToUpload", fileToUpload.files[0]);`, the passing of data. But it does not work if `form.append("photoToUpload", fileToUpload.files[0]);` is included. The error displayed is "Undefined Index: photoToUpload".

Using the line `console.log(fileToUpload.files[0]);` actually displays the details of the image I'm trying to upload. And I used `for (var pair of form.entries()) { console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); }` to confirm the contents of the FormData before calling Ajax to make sure it has the right contents.

Additional information : The code works in localhost but not on the live server. Server has a bit higher PHP version but still 7.2, has the same Jquery version. Not sure what else to check.

```
var fileToUpload = document.getElementById('photoToUpload');

// To check if fileToUpload has the contents
console.log(fileToUpload.files[0]); 
 
var form = new FormData();
form.append("photoToUpload", fileToUpload.files[0]);
form.append("caption", "Sample caption");

// To check if the FormData has the contents
for (var pair of form.entries()) { 
  console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}

$.ajax({
  url : "addToDB",
  type : "POST",
  data : form,
  cache : false,
  contentType : false,
  processData : false,
  success : function(response) {                
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Backend:

```
echo $_POST['caption'];
echo $_FILE['photoToUpload']['name'];

// This also work in displaying the data passed in array format
print_r($_POST); // Displays photoToUpload as undefined
print_r($_FILES); // Empty array for photoToUpload
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is on the backend side. Could you please share the handler part where you see the error?

Comment: @PavloZhukov, I've updated the question to show what my backend looks. It's pretty straightforward for now, just returning the data passed and displaying it in console log.